# How to classify sequence of images with keras deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I want to make a classification model for a sequence of CT images with Keras. my dataset obtains from 50 patients and each patient has 1000 images. For a patient, each image has a meaningful relationship with the previous image. I want to use these meaningful relationships, so I don't know how to build a model for such this problem. can you please give me an idea or examples?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is in the context of Sequence Classification. You need to classify sequences of images. In this case, a model is needed to learn two aspects :

1. Features of the images
2. Features of the sequence ( temporal or time-related features )

> This might sound similar to video classification in which a video is a sequence of several frames. See [here](https://blog.coast.ai/five-video-classification-methods-implemented-in-keras-and-tensorflow-99cad29cc0b5).

**For extracting features from images:**

Most real-world cases use Convolutional Neural Networks. They use layers like Max Pooling and Convolution. They are excellent at extracting features from a 3D input like an image. You can learn more from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-convolutional-neural-networks-the-eli5-way-3bd2b1164a53).

**For handling temporal data:**

Here's where you will require an RNN ( Recurrent Neural Network ). LSTM ( Long-Short Term Memory ) cells are popular RNN as they can hold a stronger memory than traditional RNNs.

> RNNs preserve the hidden layer activations and use them in processing each and every term in a sequence. Hence, while processing the 2nd image in a sequence, the RNN has knowledge or activations of the 1st image in that same sequence.

You can know more from [here](https://skymind.ai/wiki/lstm).

**Finally, we require a fusion of both the above networks:**

A CNN-LSTM network uses both convolutional as well as LSTM cells to classify the image sequences.

[image: This is how they look.]

You can refer [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cnn-long-short-term-memory-networks/) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/get-started-with-using-cnn-lstm-for-forecasting-6f0f4dde5826)

Hope that helps you. :-)

Comment: How about loading the data, what can I use instead of train_datagen.flow_from_directory / datagenerator?